# Find the line of intersection of the planes

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The planes are x+2y+3z=1 and x-y+z=1. My guess would be to set them equal to each other, since they are both equal to 1, we could write that as x+2y+3z=x-y+z. This simplifies to 3y+2z=0, it doesn't seem like this would be our answer though.

Update: I now understand that the cross product of the two normal vectors gives us the direction vector for the line that we're interested in finding but I don't know how to find a point on the line.

Comment: Find the normal vectors for each planes and take the cross product of those vectors. The cross product yields a new vector parallel to the line of intersection. Use this to solve.

Comment: @mathtastic I now understand how to find the direction vector of the line but how do we find a point on the line so we can create an equation for the line.

Comment: Ah! Yes, I should have included that information. You can solve the two equations simultaneously. The easiest method would be to use a simple augmented matrix (like those listed below by a few posters)and then apply gaussian elimination to solve your augmented matrix. Here is a link to a wiki than explains gaussian elimination and has a nice example that helps illustrate the method! Don't let the name trick you - it is a very easy process and taking a few minutes to learn the method will help a lot with cal 3. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination

Comment: Excellent, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $x+2y+3z=1$ and $x-y+z=1$ **iff** $3y+2z=0$ and $x=1-2y-3z$ **iff** $y=-{2 \over 3} z$ and $x=1-2y-3z=1-{5 \over 3} z$.

So, the line is given by $\{(1-{5 \over 3} z, -{2 \over 3} z, z) \}_{z \in \mathbb{R}}$.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand this.

Comment: There are two equivalences. Which one are you having a problem with? I have fixed some errors above.

Comment: Alright, I understand what you've written now.

Answer (score 1):

The method is explained [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane-PlaneIntersection.html).

Comment: @MartinG I don't understand how I'm supposed to find a point on the line.

Comment: See NovaDenizen's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Your planes are equivalent to the linear system

$$\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
x \\ y \\ z \\
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\ 1 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$

If the normal vectors are nonzero and are not parallel then you can always perform row operations so that $\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\0\\\end{array}\right]$ is in one column and $\left[\begin{array}{c}0 \\1\\\end{array}\right]$ is in another one.  Then you can pick an arbitrary value for the variable corresponding to the third column and determine the corresponding values for the other two.

$$\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 2 & 3 & 1\\
1 & -1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{array}\right]\\
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 2 & 3 & 1\\
0 & -3 & -2 & 0\\
\end{array}\right]\\
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & \frac53 & 1\\
0 & -3 & -2 & 0\\
\end{array}\right]\\
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & \frac53 & 1\\
0 & 1 & \frac23 & 0\\
\end{array}\right]\\
$$

Picking $z=0$ gives $(1,0,0)$.  Picking $z=3$ gives $(-4,-2,3)$.

Comment: Good explanation, although I need to study up on the notation you used, I get it in principle.

Comment: It's just matrix notation for linear algebra, basic stuff.  See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix#Existence_and_number_of_solutions) for a decent starting point.